# How to deal with solr query string too long issue?

Tags: solr, jsonp

All:

Could any one show me how to use post to submit the query( cos sometimes the query string is too long)?

Because I am doing a cross domain request, and from posts which said I should use JSONP. But problem is: JSONP using GET to submit the request which limits the length of query string, I wonder if there is any other way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201195/is-there-a-size-or-term-limit-for-a-solr-query-string-when-using-http-post

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Thanks for link. But I still not quite understand how to do this in JSONP, could you give me a example doing this( cos if I do not use JSONP, the browser just now allow me to do this query, I got No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present error)